# The Unity Method onCollisionEnter() has incorrect case

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to detect a collision between two objects in Unity

I cannot get it to enter the onCollisionEnter function

I can type it in as OnColliosnEnter, and onCollisionEnter, both seem to build
however, both give me the same incorrect case error. However when I use the OnCollisionEnter notation, I also get "has an Incorrect Signature" error. I cannot find an explanation for either online

[image]

What's the difference between them? Which one do I need to use?

Neither ever gets called when two objects collide

```
public class MoveToTarget : Agent
{
    //[SerializeField] private Transform target;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject target;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject walls;
 //....
    private void onCollisionEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.name == "Target")
        {
            AddReward(10);
            EndEpisode();
        }
        else if (collider.gameObject.name == "Walls")
        {
            AddReward(-2);
            EndEpisode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).  Parameter is `Collision` not `Collider`, thats probably the reason

Answer (score 2):

Use OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) instead of OnCollisionEnter(Collider collider). just like the comment said.